# precautions related to run() method of thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

Last week I went for an interview, and during the interview one of the interviewer asked this question with me,

```
Q. What precaution do you take will writing a run() method?
```

and my answer was deadlock, livelock, synchronization, starvation and few of the overhead, but 
he was not satisfied with my answer. He told no there are some other thing when we write run() method you should take care of...

```
I wrote run() like this during interview.. 

class DrawCircle implements Runnable {

    public void run(){
        //some code here
    }

}
```

can any body tell me what is proper way of writing run() in any Runnable thread?

Comment: I would have asked the answer from interviewer before leaving. These are crappy questions, because it is not about what is right or wrong, but about judging what is there in interviewers mind, and you have answer that. Bad interviewing practice.

Comment: i also did same thing. I asked him answer for the question but he told you can get from google.

Comment: crappy response, a good interviewer will always explain you.

Comment: The top hit on Google is this post, and none of the rest of the top ten are relevant. If he really knew the answer he should certainly have told you. And is he testing your ability to Google? or expecting you to know it by heart? and if the latter, why, when it's on Google? Maybe he got the *question* from Google. Stupid question and stupider reponse. Consider it a bullet dodged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing obvious but these:

1. Make sure your `run` method actually returns after finishing the task or it timeout after some defined threshold. If `run()` is stuck somewhere then thread will never finish. And if for some reason all your threads are getting stuck, and you have large number of threads, then it may crash your system.
2. If you are extending the Thread class, then make sure that you override the correct method. To be safe, adding `@override` on top of the method is good.
3. If you are implementing an anonymous thread then make sure you assign it to a `Thread` instance. If your `run` method goes into a bad state/infinte loop. You may be able to interrupt the thread using the instance.

Comment: let me clear the code above...

Comment: Point 1 - what if I want the method to run for the lifetime of the application?  That is not an uncommon requirement.